# Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: literal array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

Warning: pg_query():

I try this code,import dbf into postgres but get that erorr

```
if (pg_query($conn, "$sql"))
{
    $i++;   
    if ( $i % 100 == 0 ) 
    {
        echo '.'; 
    } 
} 
else 
{
    echo "SQL : ".$sql;     
    if ($die_on_pgsql_error) 
    {
        die;
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks .

This complete code in [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwGraE5kFh3Q0FBUXE4NmZTWXc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Tip: include the actual query when you're writing about an error!

Comment: Im Sory. This my complete code. to long to write this comment : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwGraE5kFh3Q0FBUXE4NmZTWXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show the *query text*. Just the query. The SQL.

Comment: if I use "{" in my sql =   $sql = 'INSERT INTO "'.$tbl.'" ("'. strtolower($col).'") VALUES ("{'.$val.'}")'; the result in the table in postgre the "{" character inputed in the database. When I delete "{" character, that error was happen.

Comment: INSERT INTO "MSMHS" ("kdptimsmhs", "kdjenmsmhs", "kdpstmsmhs") VALUES ('111111', 'C', '74201');

Answer (score 0):

> if I use `"{"` in my sql = `$sql = 'INSERT INTO "'.$tbl.'" ("'. strtolower($col).'") VALUES ("{'.$val.'}")';` the result in the table in postgre the `{` character inputed in the database.

Yes, that's what should happen.

You appear to be trying to pass an array, or concatentate the text form of a PHP array maybe. This won't work.

Use [parameterised statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) ("prepared statements") to supply parameters to SQL queries, not string concatenation.